# WP8.1 - CancellationToken and async still await forever and never end

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I have a really strange problem and I don't know how to solve it.
I have these two methods in different classes.
The first one is triggered when a button in the CommandBar is pressed.

EDIT: I created two similar but smaller methods to show you the problem:

```
    private async void runCode(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BottomAppBar.IsEnabled = false;
        object result = await endlessLoopTest();
        BottomAppBar.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private async Task<object> endlessLoopTest()
    {
        var tokenSource = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource(500);
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    //Infinite loop to test the code
                }
            }, tokenSource.Token);
            return null;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            return new TextBlock();
        }
    }
```

I added a cancellationToken that expires after 1500ms (I assume that if the interpreter takes longer to process the code, it has been trapped in a loop).

The first time I try this it usually works, but if I try again, the CommandBar buttons never get enabled again, so I assume that task is being awaited forever, and I don't know why, as I added that cancellationToken.

Do you know what could be wrong here?
Thanks for your help!

Sergio

Comment: Please provide a better code example. One that is concise, but can actually be compiled and run by other people. And it'd be nice if you could leave out the swear words too. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: lol that's the actual name of the language I'm interpreting ahahahah I forgot to cut that out, sorry :)
I edited my post with two small methods that reproduce the issue, thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are about 2/3's of the way there. When using a `CancellationToken` + `CancellationTokenSournce`, one must ask the token if it was cancelled. There are a number of ways to subscribe to that, including calling the token's [ThrowIfCancelledRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx) method or checking the token's `Boolean` property [IsCancellationRequested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx) and `break`ing out of the loop. See [Cancellation in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here's a small example that can run in a Console app. Note, in UI based apps, use `await`, not `Task.Wait()`.

```
    private static void CancelTask()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(750);
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int count = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                Console.WriteLine(count++);
                if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, cts.Token).Wait();
    }
```

The result is `0 1 2` and then the Task and program exit.

Comment: Thanks, is works! The method that could get into an infinite loop is a recursive one that also has a goto inside it, I added a ThrowIfCancelledRequest() right after the jump label, and it works :D
I just don't get how is it possibile that when debugging the app with a breakpoint it worked before I added that Throw method.
I mean, the task was canceled anyway.
Anyways, thank you so much for your help! :)